# Checking DataFrame column value for match in list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following list:

```
list = ['abc', 'ace', 'aei']
```

And I have DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['abc','abd','abe','acd','ace','aci'], "B": ""})
```

I want write a function that will, for each value in df['A'], check for any match in the list. If a match exists, add "match" for that value in df['B']. So far the for loops I've tried don't seem to be working. For example:

```
for el in df['A']:
    if el in list:
        df['B'] = "match"
    else:
        pass
```

This populates every row of df['B'] with "match". Other efforts have not populated df['B'] when there is a match.

Thanks!

Comment: `df['B'] = np.where(df['A'].isin(your_list), 'match', '')`. Don't use `list` as a variable, even in sample code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['abc', 'ace', 'aei']

dct = {"A": ['abc','abd','abe','acd','ace','aci'], "B": ""}

if len(list(set(lst) & set(dct['A']))) != 0:
    dct['B'] = 'match'


print (dct)
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'acd', 'ace', 'aci'], 'B': 'match'}
```

If you still wish to use pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

lst = ['abc', 'ace', 'aei']

dct = {"A": ['abc','abd','abe','acd','ace','aci'], "B": ""}

df['B'] = np.where(df['A'].isin(lst), 'match', '')
```

For partial matches:

```
lst = ['abc']

dct = {"A": ['abcdef','abd','abe','acd','ace','aci'], "B": ""}

if len([v for v in lst if v in " ".join(dct['A'])]) != 0:
    dct['B'] = 'match'
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['abcdef', 'abd', 'abe', 'acd', 'ace', 'aci'], 'B': 'match'}
```

OP request:

```
lst = ['abc', 'ace', 'aei']

dct = {"A": ['abcdef','aei','abe','acd','ace','aci'], "B": []}

for test in lst:
    for val in dct['A']:
        if test in val:
            dct['B'].append('match')
        else:
            dct['B'].append('nomatch')

print (dct)
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['abcdef', 'aei', 'abe', 'acd', 'ace', 'aci'], 'B': ['match', 'nomatch', 'nomatch', 'nomatch', 'nomatch', 'nomatch', 'nomatch', 'nomatch', 'nomatch', 'nomatch', 'match', 'nomatch', 'nomatch', 'match', 'nomatch', 'nomatch', 'nomatch', 'nomatch']}
```

Comment: Thank you! As a follow up, will this find complete matches only? For example, will it return a positive match of 'abc' for value 'abcdef'? How can I get it to return match for those?

Comment: Edited, if that helped think about accepting the answer ;) (gray tick top left of my answer)

Comment: That added "match" to all 'A' values, not just the partial match.

Comment: What do you mean? There is only one value in dct['A'] which is a list. And since dct['B'] is not a list, the match value is for the whole list, not specific to item. Could you clarify?

Comment: I see. I am trying to find partial or complete matches for every value in 'A' for every value in dct. The end result I'm trying to script is a DataFrame where every 'A' value is checked against a corpus of n-grams (lst) for any exact or partial match. If that match exists, populate that row of 'B' with "match'. If not, pass.

Comment: so do you want a list in 'B'? With value in list is match or nomatch, and index in B refers to index in A. is that ok?

Comment: Yes that's right I think. I can convert lists back to df columns easily enough.

Comment: See my edit. If that helped, do not forget to accept the answer ;) (gray tick top left of my answer)